# Force MS RemoteApp to save to Client Drive

Tags: remoteapp

I'm using an older software with a dbase database. I'd like to deploy it as a remoteapp, and from my testing this seems quite possible.

My question is this:

This application generates excel and csv files, how can I force remote app to save these files to the clients machine and not save anything generated (or through a save dialog) to the server?

Comment: Or, you could just allow them to do so, but have the Windows Task Scheduler delete them every now and then, so that when people save on the server, they cannot use them anymore.

Comment: This is a solid idea. However I'm afraid this would result in additional support call. Which I'd like to avoid.

Comment: Simply create accounts for them in the domain that the server is a part of or controls, then disallow those users permission to access the C:\ drive or any other local hard drives so that all that they can access is the `tsclient`.

Comment: Did that solve the problem?